# how to inject $scope object to the dialog template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qxsq3LAnC3SWo6AsMqBM?p=preview) with a dialog example that uses the resolve attribute of the option object, based on this [example](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/dialog/README.md#dialogtemplateurl-controller).
Basically what I want to do is to pass the title variable to be used in the dialog template:

```
var title         = "azerty";
```

Using the resolve attribute of the dialog options object:

```
resolve:       {title: angular.copy(title)}
```

And then inject it to the dialog controller and assign it to a $scope variable:

```
controllers.DialogController = function($scope, dialog, title) {
    $scope.title = title;
```

But I get this Error:

> Error: Unknown provider: azertyProvider <- azerty

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Starting with release `0.2.0`
(https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#020-2013-03-03)
we've updated the resolve syntax so it follows the one used by the
[$routeProvider](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeProvider). In practice it means that a value in the resolve
object must be a function:

```
resolve: {
  title: function() {
    return angular.copy(title);
  }
}
```

Here is the working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/qmNUsWK7RGeAjXcANuWv?p=preview

BTW, you don't need (and even should not) include Bootstrap's
JavaScript. This project doesn't have dependencies on any external
JavaScript (beside AngularJS itself) so you don't need jQuery either.

Comment: Thanks for answering here and in the [google group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!category-topic/angular-ui/bootstrap/sfO4LpM96ro).

Comment: There is a closing curly bracket missing at the end of the resolve option.